# How to make a shot impact in a rectangle only output one event?

Tags: python, pygame

In pygame, I am trying to make my points increase by 1000 every time a shot impacts my zombie, who's positions are zhot[XX] and zhot[YY]. I attempted to accomplish this by creating a rectangle around my zombie, and using the collidepoint function, however as my shot passes through the rectangle, every change in it's position counts as 1000 points, so shooting one zombie will give me something like 30000 points. How can I fix this?

```
for shot in shots:
    zomrect2=Rect(zhot[XX],zhot[YY],49,38)
    if zomrect2.collidepoint(shot[X],shot[Y]):     
        points+=1000
```

Comment: Do you want the bullet to not die on impact? And add points every collision with a zombie, just not if it's already hit that one?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've awarded points, you need to `break` out of the for loop.

```
for shot in shots:
    zomrect2=Rect(zhot[XX],zhot[YY],49,38)
    if zomrect2.collidepoint(shot[X],shot[Y]):     
        points+=1000 
        break #no more points will be awarded, there's no point wasting computation checking the rest.
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the loop you posted runs inside your main loop and is invoked every iteration of the main loop.

You should remove the `shot` from the `shots` list once it hit your zombie, so it won't be checked again for collision in the next iteration of the main loop.

```
zomrect2=Rect(zhot[XX],zhot[YY],49,38)
# make a copy of the list so we can savely remove items
# from it while iterating over the list
for shot in shots[:]: 
  if zomrect2.collidepoint(shot[X],shot[Y]):     
    points += 1000 
    shots.remove(shot) 
    # and also do whatever you have to do to 
    # erase the shot objects from your game
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the fact that the points have been awarded already.  It's not really clear how/when the method or function awarding points is being called, but something like this perhaps:

```
points_awarded = False
for shot in shots:
    zomrect2=Rect(zhot[XX],zhot[YY],49,38)
    if zomrect2.collidepoint(shot[X],shot[Y]) and not points_awarded:      
        points_awarded = True
        points+=1000
```